# PHP не удается передать значения в href

Tags: php, html

```
 <?php

 $t = date("H");

 if ($t == "02") 
 {echo $url0 = "https://google.com";}
 elseif($t == "01") {echo $url= "https://amazon.com";}  
 else {
 echo "Have a good night!";}
 ?>
<a href="'.$url0.'" class="td_download_btn"><i class="download_icon"></i> Get Telegram for<b>Windows</b></a>
```

Не удается передать значения `$url0` до `href`. Закинуть в внутрь цикла не выйдет уже пробовал, ломает кучу всего. При исполнении просто пишет что файл не может найти хотя это ссылка.
Пробовал `<?$url0?>` `<=?$url0?>` так ошибки не выдает но кнопка перестает работать.
Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 3):

Ошибки:

1. Вы переменную `$url0` определяете только в условии `if ($t == "02")`. В условии `elseif($t == "01")` определяется уже переменная `$url`, а в условии `else` не определяется вообще никаких переменных
2. Конструкция `echo $url0 = "https://google.com";` эквивалентна двум операторам

   ```php
   $url0 = "https://google.com";
   echo $url0;
   ```

   врядли вам нужен здесь `echo`
3. Конструкция `<? ... ?>` это короткая запись конструкции `<?php ... ?>` и может быть отключена в настройках. Если вы хотите что-то вывести этой конструкцией, то вам нужно писать `<?php echo $url0; ?>`, а конструкции `<=? ... ?>` нет вообще. Вместо нее есть конструкция `<?= ... ?>` которая эквивалентна конструкции `<?php echo ...; ?>` и именно она вам и нужна
4. В записи

   ```html
   <a href="'.$url0.'" class="td_download_btn">
   ```

   вы переборщили с кавычками. Одинарные кавычки тут не нужны.

Итого правильный код

```php
 <?php

 $t = date("H");

 if ($t == "02")  {
    $url0 = "https://google.com";
 } elseif ($t == "01") {
    $url0= "https://amazon.com";
 }   else {
    $url0 = "javascript:void(0)";
}
?>
<a href="<?=$url0?>" class="td_download_btn">Test</a>
```

Ссылка на [Ideone](https://ideone.com/1YInBt)

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так..

```html
<?php
 $t = date("H");

 if ($t == "02") {
   $url0 = "https://google.com";
 }
 elseif($t == "01") {
   $url = "https://amazon.com";
 }  
 else {
   echo "Have a good night!";
 }
?>


<a href="<?=$url0?>" class="td_download_btn"><i class="download_icon"></i> Get Telegram for<b>Windows</b></a>
```

При задании переменных не нужно писать echo.
Знак равно "=" в

```php
<?=переменная?>
```

равнозначен echo.

echo нужно использовать только для вывода чего-то..

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?= $url0; ?>" class="td_download_btn"><i class="download_icon"></i> Get Telegram for<b>Windows</b></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($t == "02") {
    $url0 = "https://google.com";
} elseif($t == "01") {
    $url= "https://amazon.com";
} else {
    $error = "Have a good night!";
}
```

echo - функция вывода строки

```
<a href="<?=$url0?>" class="td_download_btn"><i class="download_icon"></i> Get Telegram for<b>Windows</b></a>
```